# not able to delete the helm release using cornjob in kubernets

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

Here is the yaml file what should find and delete the helm release, but is not able to delete the same.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cronbox
  namespace: avinash-new
spec:
  serviceAccount: default
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: cronbox
            image: busybox
            args:
            #command: 'sh'
            - '-uexc'
            - 'releases=$(helm ls -a -q nodejs-chart.*); helm delete --purge $releases;'
            env:
            - name: TILLER_NAMESPACE
              value: mynamespace-build
            - name: KUBECONFIG
              value: /kube/config
            #volumeMounts:
            #- mountPath: /kube
              #name: kubeconfig
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: kubeconfig
            configMap:
              name: cronjob-kubeconfig
```

Please help me with the same. the expectation is "Need to delete the helm releases periadically like every 5 mins".

Comment: Why not?  What happens?  (Are you using the old version 2 of Helm still?)

Answer (score 0):

`image: busybox` does not come with `helm` command. You can try [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/helm) instead.

Comment: still it did not work, I am able to pull the image but not able to delete the helm release :-( @gohm'c

Comment: It works. But your `args` are wrong (eg. -uexc?), learn how [helm uninstall](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_uninstall/) works first.